# Android - SQLite issue with adding more tables to database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, appsettings

First of all I created my prescription_table and that worked. 
Then I tried to add a second table to the database called patient_table. 
However I am getting this error "

```
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
        (no such table: patient_table (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO patient_table(PPS,CARINGID,DOB,ADDRESS,SNAME,PATIENTTYPE,PATIENTMEDCON,FNAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?))
```

I tried changing the database version number from 1 to 2 however this made my app crash. I have also tried to uninstall the application from my android device however it is still giving me the same error.

Any help would be grateful.

```
package com.example.medicationmanagementsystem.DAO;
//code below is based on AndroidSQLite Tutorial Android CRUD Tutorial with SQLite (Create, Read, Update, Delete), ProgrammingKnowledge, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDZES1wtKUY
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Create Database
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ManagementSystem.db";
    //Create patient table
    public static final String TABLE_PATIENT = "patient_table";
    public static final String COL_PATIENT_PATIENTID = "PATID";
    public static final String COL_PATIENT_FNAME = "FNAME";
    public static final String COL_PATIENT_SNAME = "SNAME";
    public static final String COL_PATIENT_PPS = "PPS";
    public static final String COL_PATIENT_DOB = "DOB";
    public static final String COL_PATIENT_ADDRESS = "ADDRESS";
    public static final String COL_PATIENT_TYPE = "PATIENTTYPE";
    public static final String COL_PATIENT_MEDCOND = "PATIENTMEDCON";
    public static final String COL_PATIENT_CARINGID = "CARINGID";

    //Create prescription table
    public static final String TABLE_PRESCRIPTION = "prescription_table";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION_ID = "PRESCRIPTIONID";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__PATIENTID = "PATIENTID";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__DATE = "DATE";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__DRUGNAME = "DRUGNAME";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__CONCENTRATION = "CONCENTRATION";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__DOSAGE = "DOSAGE";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__PREPARATION = "PREPARATION";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__STARTDATE = "STARTDATE";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__ENDDATE = "ENDDATE";
    public static final String COL_PRESCRIPTION__DOCTORID = "DOCTORID";



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String patienttable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PATIENT + "(PATID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FNAME TEXT, SNAME TEXT, PPS TEXT, DOB TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PATIENTTYPE TEXT, PATIENTMEDCON TEXT, CARINGID INTEGER)";
        String prescriptiontable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRESCRIPTION + "(PRESCRIPTIONID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PATIENTID INTEGER, DATE TEXT, DRUGNAME TEXT, CONCENTRATION TEXT, DOSAGE TEXT, PREPARATION TEXT, STARTDATE TEXT, ENDDATE TEXT, DOCTORID INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(patienttable);
        db.execSQL(prescriptiontable);
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_PATIENT);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_PRESCRIPTION);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    //insert patient data
    public boolean insertPatientData(String fname, String sname, String pps, String dob, String address, String patienttype, String patientmedcon, String caringid) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues1 = new ContentValues();
        contentValues1.put(COL_PATIENT_FNAME, fname);
        contentValues1.put(COL_PATIENT_SNAME, sname);
        contentValues1.put(COL_PATIENT_PPS, pps);
        contentValues1.put(COL_PATIENT_DOB, dob);
        contentValues1.put(COL_PATIENT_ADDRESS, address);
        contentValues1.put(COL_PATIENT_TYPE, patienttype);
        contentValues1.put(COL_PATIENT_MEDCOND,patientmedcon);
        contentValues1.put(COL_PATIENT_CARINGID, caringid);
        long result= db.insert(TABLE_PATIENT,null, contentValues1);
        if (result == 1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    //insert prescription data
    public boolean insertData(String patientid, String date, String drugname, String concentration,String dosage, String preparation, String startdate, String enddate, String doctorid) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues2 = new ContentValues();
        contentValues2.put(COL_PRESCRIPTION__PATIENTID, patientid);
        contentValues2.put(COL_PRESCRIPTION__DATE, date);
        contentValues2.put(COL_PRESCRIPTION__DRUGNAME, drugname);
        contentValues2.put(COL_PRESCRIPTION__CONCENTRATION, concentration);
        contentValues2.put(COL_PRESCRIPTION__DOSAGE, dosage);
        contentValues2.put(COL_PRESCRIPTION__PREPARATION, preparation);
        contentValues2.put(COL_PRESCRIPTION__STARTDATE, startdate);
        contentValues2.put(COL_PRESCRIPTION__ENDDATE, enddate);
        contentValues2.put(COL_PRESCRIPTION__DOCTORID, doctorid);
        long result= db.insert(TABLE_PRESCRIPTION,null, contentValues2);
        if (result == 1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
        //END

    }

    //Coding with mitch tutorial
    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRESCRIPTION, null);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to uninstall the app from the device so the database is deleted and then rerun to recreate the database and the table, because the onCreate () method of your DatabaseHelper is not called every time you run the app, but only when there is no database and it needs to be created.

Comment: Hi I have tried this, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you get the same error for prescription_table after you uninstalled the app?

Comment: In which device do you face this? Emulator or real device? if real then what is it.

Comment: No it is just happening to the patient_table. The prescription_table is reading and writing fine.

Comment: I am using a Samsung Galaxy Tab A.

Comment: This means that the app was not really uninstalled. Check your manifest. If there is a line: `android:allowBackup="true"`. If it exists change it to: `android:allowBackup="false"` and then rerun, uninstall and rerun.

Comment: I have changed this to false and now my app is crashing.

Comment: When an app crashes you check the error log. The database must be deleted from the device in order for the code to create the tables. If you can't do it in the current device, try it in a clean device.

Comment: Try clearing your data and cache before uninstalling the app from App Settings, then re-run it will work.

Comment: Got it by clearing data and cache and getting rid of this.getReadableDatabase and this.getWritableDatabase in OnCreate method. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be trying to open the database (using this.**getReadableDatabase** or this.**getWritableDatabase**) in the **onCreate** method as at this stage a getWritableDatabase is underway and as such you will get an ***java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively***.

That is when you get an instance of the DatabaseHelper, the database is not created or opened. It's not until you invoke getWritableDatabase (implicitly (e.g. via an insert) or explicitly) that an attempt is made to open the database and create it if it doesn't already exist. Thus calling get????ableDatabase will be a recursion since it is already getting the database.

> I tried changing the database version number from 1 to 2 however this
> made my app crash.

As onUpgrade is also invoked when getting the database, it calling onCreate also fails because of the recursion.

As such change the **onCreate** method to be :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String patienttable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PATIENT + "(PATID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FNAME TEXT, SNAME TEXT, PPS TEXT, DOB TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PATIENTTYPE TEXT, PATIENTMEDCON TEXT, CARINGID INTEGER)";
    String prescriptiontable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRESCRIPTION + "(PRESCRIPTIONID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PATIENTID INTEGER, DATE TEXT, DRUGNAME TEXT, CONCENTRATION TEXT, DOSAGE TEXT, PREPARATION TEXT, STARTDATE TEXT, ENDDATE TEXT, DOCTORID INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(patienttable);
    db.execSQL(prescriptiontable);
    //this.getReadableDatabase(); //<<<<< MUST NOT BE USED In onCreate
    //this.getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<< MUST NOT BE USED in onCreate
}
```

- Of cousre you would likely delete the lines rather than comment them out.

Before running the App it would be best to uninstall the App (this should overcome the initial issue which is due to onCreate only being called once for the lifetime of the database).

- As such, if you change the schema, when developing the App, you would typicaly delete the database (uninstalling the App or deleting the App's data will do this).
- Making the amendments above to the onCreate method would also allow increasing the version number to work as it calls onCreat.

P.S. checking the return value from the insert for 1 will only return true for the very fist insert, as only at that stage is the return value (the **rowid** (PATID and PRESCRIPTIONID will be aliases of the rowid)), for subsquent inserts the value be will be greater than 1.

I'd suggest that instead of using :-

```
    long result= db.insert(.........);
    if (result == 1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
```

That you use :-

```
return (db.insert(......) > 0);
```

or

```
return (db.insert(......) != -1)
```

- *(**-1** indicates that no row was inserted).*

## TESTING

The above has been tested using you Database helper with rows being succesfully inserted.

The following code in an activity was used for the test :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDBHlpr.insertData("1234567890","2018-01-01","X","50","4 times daily","Shake","2018-01-01","2018-03-01","DOC001");
        mDBHlpr.insertPatientData("Fred","Bloggs","pps001","1974-01-01","1 Somewhere Street","X","MECON001","001");

        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getListContents();
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("SCRIPTINFO","ID is " +csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_PRESCRIPTION_ID)));
        }

        csr = mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase().query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_PATIENT,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("PATIENTINFO","Patient Name is " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_PATIENT_FNAME)));
        }
        
    }
}
```

The result (from an initial run after uninstalling the App) was :-

```
2019-11-18 12:57:10.362 D/SCRIPTINFO: ID is 1
2019-11-18 12:57:10.363 D/PATIENTINFO: Patient Name isFred
```